# I need to filter based of off objects that are nested inside a list of objects

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, filter

So all of my other filters work correctly, so I know it is just for the nested objects. But I am not sure how to approach it. So simply put the data looks like this (there are many more columns, but this gets the point across):

[{firstName:"Tom", lastName:"Smith", Sites:[{siteName:"Washington"}, {siteName:"Arkansas"}, {firstName:"Mary", lastName:"Smith", Sites:[{siteName:"Washington"}]

The site details are nested inside the the users details, this is because a user can belong to many sites. I need to be able to show all customers that belong to a specific site. And if I filter by first or last name it works, but my logic for siteName is wrong.

`{FilterOperation.Contains, (usersQuery) => { return usersQuery.Where(c => c.Sites.Any(s => s.SiteName.ToLower() == this.Value.ToLower())); } }`

For some reason the data is not being passes inside the Any for the comparison. It is acting like Sites is empty. The only guess I have is that I need to create a separate filter for site objects that is called from within this filter??

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using ef core for usersQuery and Sites being navigation property to the User. If it is the case it is because of lazy loadign feature in ef core, you need to add .Include(user=>user.Sites) when the query is formed to load Sites as children.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! This did it. For some reason I never considered that the data just was not there lol!